# Article table has a lot of null. What is the best way to prevent null in MySQL

Tags: database-design, mysql-5.6

I'm optimizing table schema.

My case is like.

User can generate an article.

It has a lot of item. like name, age, sex, address, hobby...

name, sex is a required entry.

but age, address, hobby is not required entry.

Table has a lot of null currently.

Sometimes null is changed attribute domain value when user edit article.

```
  name   |   age   |   sex   |   address   |   hobby
  aa         null      male        null        soccer
  bb         17        female      null        null
```

So I'm thinking 2 case.

1.

```
Table: article
Column: id, name, sex
Primary key: id

Table: article_sub
Column: article_id, type(0:age, 1:address, 2:hobby), value
Primary key: article_id, type
```

This case have to set varchar data type to value.

Because age is integer, address is string... so size is demerit.

2.

```
Table: article
Column: id, name, sex
Primary key: id

Table: article_sub_integer
Column: article_id, value
Primary key: article_id

Table: article_sub_string
Column: article_id, type(0:address, 1:hobby), value
Primary key: article_id, type
```

This case I have to refer 3 table.

Which way is the better?

If you have other idea Please tell me.

Thank you.

Comment: *Which way is the better?* The best way is do nothing I think. Why you are so afraid of nulls?

Comment: You should be afraid of nulls if you have a table that holds more than 1 entity (god-table anti-pattern), like having a table for both Users and Articles in which more than half of the fields will be null by design. Otherwise, it's OK to keep optional fields with null values.

Comment: @Akina I think Null doesn't satisfy normalization.

Comment: @EzLo Thank you for your advise. "optional field can be null"

Comment: *Null doesn't satisfy normalization* Why??? Normalization says nothing about specific values (both existing and absent).

Comment: @Akina age attribute data type is integer. I think age attribute domain is 0 ~ 132... null satisfy integer ? So, sometimes null is changed attribute domain value.

Comment: Optimizing for what? You say "null is bad for normalization" and then you propose two solutions which are horrible for normalization. Especially the one where you separate the columns based on type. It's also unclear how an article can have an age, sex, and a hobby. That sounds more like a user/person type of table. You should probably work out the schema so it's logically correct and properly normalized. Don't know much about MySQL internals (vs. Postgres), but this "optimize for nulls" thing seems unnecessary or at the least premature.

Answer (score 0):

If you are short of storage and database is big enough you can reduce the size ot table but the price is significantly higher CPU and RAM consumption. Just split the table

```
PERSON 
+----+------+------+-------------+
| ID | name | attr | description |
+----+------+------+-------------+
```

into the two tables:

```
PERSON
+----+------+------+
| ID | name | attr |
+----+------+------+

P_DESCR
+------+-------------+
| P_ID | description |
+------+-------------+
```

Each time you need the full info do a `JOIN..ON`

```
SELECT * 
  FROM      person  AS w
  LEFT JOIN p_descr AS z ON z.p_id = w.id
 WHERE w.id = 1234
;
```

`LEFT JOIN` fill description column by `NULL` if no according row in the `P_DESCR` table for certain `PERSON`

Both approaches - with `NULL`s and `JOIN`s are valid but you can choose what is more suitable for your needs.

Comment: Null flag needs 1 byte per each nullable field per record. Additional P_ID field takes more (I think). Where is a size profit? And don't forget about additional volume for an unique index by P_ID field...

Comment: @Akina This is true because default row format for InnoDB is `compact` by default.

Comment: Additionally the storage block-granularity causes the table size may both decrease and not decrease after nullability removing.

Comment: @Akina I prefer `CREATE TABLE..SELECT` instead of `ALTER TABLE` in such cases.